# Best Match of each element in of a string with many strings

Tags: r, analytics, data-manipulation

Input Data:

```
a <- c("coca cola","hot coffee","Running Shoes","Table cloth",
       ”mobile phones under 5000”,”Amazon kindle”)
b <- c("running shoes","plastic cup","pizza","Let’s go to hill","motor van",
       "coffee table","drinking coffee on a rainy day",”Best mobile phones under 10000”,
       ”kindle e-books”,”Coffee Cup”)
```

Match each word of each sentence of a vector (here vector a) to all strings in a separate vector(here vector b) word by word and get the best match.

[image: The expected output]

Logic:
All sentence of vector “a” has to be matched with all sentences of vector “b” word by word and a percentage has to be calculated. 
There can be only one best match per sentence of vector “a”.

Example 1: “Running Shoes” in vector “a” matched perfectly with “Running Shoes” in vector “b” and the `percentage_match` is 100% (since both the words matched)

Example 2: the best match of  “hot coffee”  may be  “drinking coffee on a rainy day” or “coffee table” or “Coffee cup” and the percentage_match is 50% (since only “coffee”, matched out of “hot coffee” in all the cases). In such scenario, where there is more than one contender with same max `percentage_match`, we will choose the best match with the lowest string length i.e “coffee table” and “coffee cup” gets priority over “drinking coffee on a rainy day”. Even after doing this, there is a tie, we are free to choose any thing (i.e either of “Coffee Table” or “Coffee cup”, can be the best match for “hot coffee”.

Code Tried:

```
as <- strsplit(a, " ")
bs <- strsplit(b, " ")

matchFun <- function(x, y) length(intersect(x, y)) / length(x) * 100
mx <- outer(as, bs, Vectorize(matchFun))

m <- apply(mx, 1, which.max)  # the maximum column of each row

z <- unlist(apply(mx, 1, function(x) x[which.max(x)]))  # maximum percentage
z[z == 0] <- NA  # this gives you the NA if you want it

data.frame(a, Matching_String=b[m], match_perc=z)
```

Problem faced: Since my actual data is very big (more than 2 million records are to be matched with 1 Mn record), this code takes forever.

Comment: You might want to take a loot at the `stringdist` package. Functions like `stringdist()` or `amatch()` might be suited for this task. You could also take a look at `agrepl()` (is included in base R).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this using `stringdistmatrix` from package `stringdist`. Basically, we are calculating the distance between the strings in `a` and `b`. Then we keep the smallest distance.  There will always be a match, even if the distance is a high number. One thing you could do is establish a minimum distance, or NA otherwise.

```
library(stringdist)
m <- stringdistmatrix(tolower(a), tolower(b), method = "qgram")
b[apply(m, 1, which.min)]

#[1] "plastic cup"                    "coffee table"                   "running shoes"                 
#[4] "coffee table"                   "best mobile phones under 10000" "kindle e-books"
```